# LocalStorage append New Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

his is : [**My First JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b9x54LLy/). It just appends `<li></li>`. It works for LocalStorage and shows the result

```
$(".nav").append($("<li></li>").html(inputan));
```

I want append like [**My Second JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1g4nb67q/):

```
var addFolder = '<li>' +
  '<div class="zf-folder">' +
    '<a></a>' +
  '</div>' +
'</li>';

$(".nav").append($(addFolder).html(inputan));
```

This works for LocalStorage, but is not showing a result when the page is reloaded. I want to use use a method like that because my code looks like this :

[image]

With append method `$('.nav').append(addFolder);`

How can I display LocalStorage result with my second jsFiddle method?

Comment: give me reason for your downvote

Comment: DV isn't mine, but please copy+paste all relevant code in to the question. Images of code are next to useless

Comment: sorry, thanks for your appreciation for editing my question. I've been confused with my suck code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `addFolder` inside your `submitButton` click handler, hence it is only available in the handler function scope.

```
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
  var inputan = $("#input_nameFolder").val();

 // move the below variable outside of this function 
  var addFolder = '<li>' +
    '<div class="zf-folder">' +
      '<a></a>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</li>';
  ...
});
```

Move `addFolder` outside of the function and it should work.

[Updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g4nb67q/1/).

**Edit: To get correct index**

You can add a function that returns the `addFolder` with the current/updated index. The same function can be used for first time rendering on page load and every time on adding item from the input.

Something like:

```
var count = 1;
function getNewList() {
  var addFolder = '<li data-index="' + (count++) + '">' +
    '<div class="zf-folder">' +
    '<a></a>' +
    '</div>' +

    '</li>';
  return addFolder;
}
```

You can check out here:
[Edited Fiddle for index](https://jsfiddle.net/1g4nb67q/10/)

> // check for the `data-index` on `li` items in the console

Comment: does the method make my index work? for id? sorry this is not on the question, but it is in the picture.

Comment: im adding index id `_zindex` on the variable addFolder

Comment: Aww Cool, I can use what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why the result just, <li></li> ? not include <div> ? pls reply